# How can I compare two different values(array) in one dictionary?

Tags: python, dictionary, compare

I want to compare two values(they are lists)  in a dictionary and if they have at least one common element I take their keys as a tuple. for my purpose, there is no difference between (k1,k2) and (k2,k1). 
I did this. But the problem is my data is huge and this way is very slow!

```
paths = {0:[1,2,3,4],1:[2,5,6],3:[5,8,9],4:[1,3,4]}
edges = []
for k1,v1 in paths.items():
        for k2,v2 in paths.items():
            if not k1 == k2:
                if [value for value in v1 if value in v2] != []:
                        edges.append((k1,k2))
```

My desire output: `[(0, 1), (0, 4), (1, 3)]`

The output I get from my code: `[(0, 1), (0, 4), (1, 0), (1, 3), (3, 1), (4, 0)]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [itertools.combinations](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations), each comparison is done only one time in this way:

```py
    import itertools
    paths = {0:[1,2,3,4],1:[2,5,6],3:[5,8,9],4:[1,3,4]}
    edges = []
    for ktuple in itertools.combinations(paths,2):
        if [value for value in paths[ktuple[0]] if value in paths[ktuple[1]]] != []:
            edges.append(ktuple)
```